# Is there a way to enable setSlaveOkay in the entire cluster

Tags: mongodb, sharding

I have a sharded cluster which has a replica set sharded, my application layer is talking to mongos , and now if my primary server goes down, my php application throws an error.
 I know this is because I have not enabled `setSlaveOkay` from the driver by doing something like this:

```
MongoCursor::$slaveOkay = true;
```

The problem with this is, where ever I am talking to db I have to add this statement.

Is there a way that I could enable this in the system level?

I tried doing `rs.slaveok()` in my primary and secondary both but still my application layer is throwing an error .

I also tried `db.getMongo().setSlaveOk()` in mongos console

The error statement is as follows:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'MongoCursorException' with message 'dbclient error communicating with server: testserver:10001'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set slaveOK at several levels in PHP: connection, database, collection, or cursor.

The various details are to be found here:

http://php.net/manual/en/mongo.queries.php

You are setting it for each cursor, which is why you are having to call it so often.  Instead you can set this at the db or collection level. In terms of what is happening behind the scenes - slaveOK is actually set for each connection - PHP is just managing that for you when you set it for the database, collection, cursor etc.

Setting it at the mongos or anywhere else in the shell simply sets it for that connection.  Once you log out, it is no longer set.

Comment: Thank you Adam , for responding to this ,my problem is, I have a huge codebase in the application layer which is very difficult to update , since the database is growing I planned to implement sharding +  replica sets but now even I just updated the connection string to talk to mongos , I am looking for a way in which I can set this setslaveok flag so that when ever I connect to mongos , this should be automatically enabled ,

Comment: right, so set it on the connection when you create it and that should cover it.....not sure I understand the issue...

Comment: Thank you Adam for the valuable information , I think I have misunderstood the way setslaveok works .

Comment: @AdamC can't we set this globally (was there any setup?)? Which makes it easy to not worry at application level.

Comment: set it on every connection and it will be set globally, there is no way to set this on the server side - it is a client side setting.